# Is there an easy way to repartition my hard disk?

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive

I partitioned my hard drive with two separate partitions for Windows and Ubuntu. Now I want to repartition my hard-drive and I'm not really sure on how to do it.

I found some programs and tools to handle the partitions but not any info on whether it's possible to merge the two seperated partitions again. Is there a way?

Comment: You need to tell us more. Why do you want to repartition the drive? Do you want to conserve Ubuntu and/or Windows?

Comment: If the partitions are different filesystems(I would expect so), then there is not way to merge them.

Answer (score 2):

[GParted](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GParted) is a great program to create, resize and delete partitions. You cannot edit the partition that your system is running from so it is probably best to run it from a live cd or [usb.](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu)

You can't really merge partitions but you can copy all the data from the first to the second, delete the first and then expand the second to fill the disk.

Windows and Ubuntu need to be on separate partitions and they have different file systems, Ubuntu uses ext4 while Windows uses NTFS, Ubuntu can read both but Windows can only read NTFS.

Comment: And if there isn't room to copy everything, copy some files, resize, copy more fies, repeat.